# Java permits primitive types in generics

Tags: java, generics

I know that java is not supposed support generic arguments which are primitive types, and sure enough something like:

```
Vector<byte> test;
```

will fail to compile.

however with a little slight-of-hand that I accidentally performed in a program, I found that it is actually possible to create a generic object with a primitive type (technique shown below)

Furthermore, java falsely allows this instance to be assigned to a variable of type `Vector<Byte>` when as the print statements show, byte.class and Byte.class are two separate beasts. Because of this, attempts to do calls on the object result in unexpected and strange behaviors/errors.

Is this a java bug? or is there some rhyme or reason to this madness? It seems like even if java allowed the unexpected behavior of creating primitive-typed generics, they should not be assignable to a generic of the wrapper type which is of a distinct class from the primitive.

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Test
{
    //the trick here is that I am basing the return type of
    //the vector off of the type that was given as the generic
    //argument for the instance of the reflections type Class,
    //however the the class given by byte.class yields a non-class
    //type in the generic, and hence a Vector is created with a
    //primitive type
    public static <Type> Vector<Type> createTypedVector(Class<Type> type)
    {
        return new Vector<Type>(0,1);
    }

    public static void main(String ... args)
    {
        //these lines are to demonstrate that 'byte' and 'Byte'
        //are 2 different class types
        System.out.println(byte.class);
        System.out.println(Byte.class);

        //this is where I create an instance of type Vector<byte>
        //and assign it to a variable of type Vector<Byte>
        Vector<Byte> primitiveTypedGenericObject = createTypedVector(byte.class);

        //this line causes unexpected exceptions to be thrown
        //because primitiveTypedGenericObject is not actually type
        //Vector<Byte>, but rather Vector<byte>
        primitiveTypedGenericObject.set(0,(byte)0xFF);

    }

}
```

Comment: When using classes of primitives, Java recommends using Byte.TYPE. Is the result the same if you replace in your code ?

Comment: yes, in fact Byte.TYPE.equals(byte.class) returns true

Comment: i'm running some tests before replying. As @Aradom responded and you already know, you're experiencing boxing problems, but as you pointed, it is strasnge that such a Vector creation be allowed in the first place.

Comment: Running your code produced an ArrayOutOfBoundsException. Is this the same for you ?

Comment: You get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0` because a byte at index 0 in the array doesn't exist - try `Vector.add()` then the `set()` call. It is unrelated to the autoboxing/unboxing you've got going on

Comment: Same conclusion for me. In fact, running with add() doesn't generate an Exception which means that boxing works well for your type. As a matter of fact though : Collections are not designed to be used with primitives, and Byte.Type or byte.class seem to me like a hack to be consistent with the language, so I discourage using your code to produce vectors of primitives. As a workaround, you could test your class for primitive and replace it with the object one =)

Comment: "this line causes unexpected exceptions to be thrown because primitiveTypedGenericObject is not actually type `Vector<Byte>`, but rather `Vector<byte>`" - Always make sure to investigate the specific cause of exceptions. It seems like you drew conclusions too quickly here.

Comment: but this was just in the sample code,I posted in my actual program the errors were much more diverse. Anyways hindsight is 20-20 but that's why I asked here instead of immediately posting a bug report

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Both `Byte.class` and `Byte.TYPE` are `Class<Byte>` objects. The latter are just used to distinguish between primitive type and object type.

Actually Byte.TYPE is defined as:

```
public static final Class<Byte> TYPE = (Class<Byte>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("byte");
```

and `getPrimitiveClass` is an opaque method which retrieves the type from the VM so we can't investigate it further.

So, even if you think that you are passing a primitive data type Class, since they don't exist (why should they, since they refer to something that is typable according to the Java typing system for objects, which doesn't include primitive types until they are boxed into wrapper classes), you are creating a `Vector<Byte>`.

But in the end this doesn't matter much, upon reaching run-time execution type annotations are erased and the generic type doesn't mean anything. Whenever you'll add a `byte` it will be autoboxed to a `Byte` object and that's it.

I have no way to test your code at the moment, which exceptions are thrown at runtime when adding items to the `Vector`?

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the vector is empty - it performs normally in my own testing if a byte is added first

Comment: You declare a vector of size zero, you can't use set with an index if the vector doesn't have room at that index. You should change initial capacity or use add instead.

Comment: @AaronWaibel The point is driven home by the fact that `type` isn't even used by `createTypedVector` and can be removed. All that matters at compile time is the type argument for `Type`, which is `Byte` in either example. +1

Answer (score 15):

You've stumbled upon autoboxing and unboxing. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

The nutshell version

```
List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>(); 
list.add(1); // works
```

`byte.class`, `int.class`, etc. resolve to `Byte`, `Integer`, etc. See the [Java Language Specification, 15.8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2):

> #### 15.8.2. Class Literals
>
> ......
>
> The type of `p.class`, where p is the name of a primitive type ([§4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)), is `Class<B>`, where B is the type of an expression of type p after boxing conversion ([§5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)).
>
> The type of `void.class` ([§8.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)) is `Class<Void>`.

Answer (score 8):

No! It is not bug. It is called **Autoboxing**. When you pass **byte** to a generic method that expects **Byte**, the compiler automatically Autoboxes it to Byte which is an instance of Object. The antithesis of that operation is called **Auto Unboxing** and that is why operations like the one shown below are legal.

```
int a = new Integer(5);
Integer b = 5;
```

Comment: this is not autoboxing, the underlying array that is created in vector is not type Byte[] but rather type byte[] and in fact as my code demonstrates,methods that would work on a type Vector<Byte> created with new Vector<Byte>(0,1) do not work on vectors created with this technique

Comment: the issue is that java cannot autobox array/generic types which is to say `byte[] test = new Byte[0];` is invalid